Increasing rate of attainment of equilibrium vs function of catalyst
Consider the following description about the Haber Ammonia process taken from NCERT for Class 12 Part 1 (2019-2020 edition). Specifically "the use of iron oxide...to increase the rate of attainment of equilibrium".

Also consider the following definition of a catalyst taken from wikipedia.

So I understand that Iron oxide acts as a catalyst. 
But what are $K_2O$ and $Al_2O_3$ used for? 
Are they catalysts? Are they promoters? Why is this specially worded to imply them increasing the rate of attainment of equilibrium. Is that not what a catayst does?
How exactly does a catalyst affect the rate of a reaction?
The next image is taken from NCERT Exemplar Solutions.

It disregards them being used as catalysts. So what are they?

it says iron oxide in the text and iron powder in the question but i believe they both work as catalysts

The catalyst is made of $\ce{Fe2O3}$ plus a small proportion of $\ce{K2O}$ and $\ce{Al2O3}$. But $\ce{Al2O3}$ and $\ce{K2O}$ alone are not Haber catalysts. $\ce{Fe2O3}$ itself is already a catalyst, but not the best one. Mixtures of $\ce{Fe2O3}$, $\ce{Al2O3}$ and $\ce{K2O}$ improve $\ce{Fe2O3}$ capacity to behave as a good catalyst. I don't know how to explain this phenomena.

does iron instead of iron oxide work?

Never heard of pure iron being a catalyst in Haber-Bosch's synthesis.

So are they like promoters? Is there a name for them?
